# Oracle 12c Installation (Grid) on RHEL 7.1 CLSRSC-214: Failed to start 'ohasd'

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c, redhat

root.sh script execution failing with following error please advice

```
./root.sh
Performing root user operation for Oracle 12c

The following environment variables are set as:
    ORACLE_OWNER= grid
    ORACLE_HOME=  /u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid

Enter the full pathname of the local bin directory: [/usr/local/bin]:
The contents of "dbhome" have not changed. No need to overwrite.
The contents of "oraenv" have not changed. No need to overwrite.
The contents of "coraenv" have not changed. No need to overwrite.


Creating /etc/oratab file...
Entries will be added to the /etc/oratab file as needed by
Database Configuration Assistant when a database is created
Finished running generic part of root script.
Now product-specific root actions will be performed.
Using configuration parameter file: /u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/crs/install/crsconfig_params
LOCAL ADD MODE
Creating OCR keys for user 'grid', privgrp 'oinstall'..
Operation successful.
LOCAL ONLY MODE
Successfully accumulated necessary OCR keys.
Creating OCR keys for user 'root', privgrp 'root'..
Operation successful.
CRS-4664: Node lrma086 successfully pinned.
2015/10/22 01:39:44 CLSRSC-330: Adding Clusterware entries to file '/etc/inittab'

2015/10/22 01:41:50 CLSRSC-214: Failed to start 'ohasd'

Failed to start the Clusterware. Last 20 lines of the alert log follow:
2015-10-22 01:39:34.970:
[client(21726)]CRS-2101:The OLR was formatted using version 4.
2015-10-22 01:39:39.368:
[client(21753)]CRS-1001:The OCR was formatted using version 4.

2015/10/22 01:41:50 CLSRSC-318: Failed to start Oracle ohasd service

Died at /u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/crs/install/crsinstall.pm line 2985.
The command '/u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/perl/bin/perl -I/u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib -I/u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/crs/install /u01/app/grid/product/12.1.0/grid/crs/install/roothas.pl ' execution failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following:
`cat /etc/systemd/system/ohasd.service`

`[Unit]`

`Description=ohasd daemon`

`[Service]`

`ExecStart=/etc/init.d/init.ohasd run >/dev/null 2>&1`

Reload the deamon:
`systemctl daemon-reload`

Enable the ohasd:
`systemctl enable ohasd.service
systemctl start ohasd.service`

Check if it is running:
`ps -ef|grep ohas`

Run the root.sh script again

Comment: Thanks, I got the error [root@lrma086 grid]# systemctl enable ohasd.service
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).